# Windows service compile with pyinstaller issue

Tags: python, compilation, windows-services, pyinstaller

I've implemented a windows service, this service has no problem before compiling with pyinstaller but after that on service start command it gives 1053 error.

Windows service code:

```
import sys
import win32service
import win32event
import socket
import win32api
import win32serviceutil


class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test"
    _svc_display_name_ = "test"
    _stoped = False

    def __init__(self, *args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, *args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self._stoped = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            if self._stoped:
                break
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: 1. Post everything about that error. 2. Which Python version are you using? 3. Which steps do you perform to compile it? 4. Is your goal to compile it or to run it?

Comment: Does it run successfully if it does not run as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem, there was a broken link to one of references in windows service. This is the right config for py2exe which solved my problem:

```
opts = {'py2exe': {
'dll_excludes': ['libzmq.pyd', 'OLEAUT32.dll', 'USER32.dll', 'SHELL32.dll', 'ole32.dll',
                 'MSVCP90.dll', 'ADVAPI32.dll', 'NETAPI32.dll', 'WS2_32.dll', 'GDI32.dll',
                 'VERSION.dll', 'KERNEL32.dll', 'WINSPOOL.DRV', 'mfc90.dll', 'ntdll.dll'],
'includes': ['UserList', 'UserString', 'commands', 'zmq.backend.cython'],
'dist_dir': "dist"
}}

setup(service=[service], options=opts, zipfile=None,data_files=[(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dist'), (zmq.libzmq.__file__,))])
```

Answer (score 0):

To use my win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework class in an exe pyInstaller produced, I needed to add a few .pyd files to the directory containing the exe e.g. win32service.pyd and win32event.pyd.  Assuming you've used the standard install paths for your libraries, these files are found here:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32